# How to Extend Yii2-user dektrium profile model to be able to adding more fields

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user

I need to override the default Profile model. I have managed to add the fields i need but there is something i am missing since. On insert and update these fields are not getting update to the database.

I have created the necessary migrations so i have these fields in the database already

What am i missing> see below my app/models/Profile.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

/**
 * Description Profile
 *
 * This form @overrides dektrium\user\models\Profile
 */
use dektrium\user\models\Profile as BaseProfile;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use Yii;
use dektrium\user\models\User;

class Profile extends BaseProfile {

    /**
     * public variables to be added to the model
     */
    public $profile_pic;
    public $expertise_id;
    public $country_id;

    public function rules() {
        $rules = parent::rules();

        $rules['profile_pic'] = ['profile_pic', 'file'];
        $rules['expertise_id'] = ['expertise_id', 'integer'];
        $rules['country_id'] = ['country_id', 'integer'];



        return $rules;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels() {
        $labels = parent::attributeLabels();
        $labels['profile_pic'] = \Yii::t('user', 'Profile Picture');
        $labels['bio'] = \Yii::t('user', 'Biography');
        $labels['expertise_id'] = \Yii::t('user', 'Expertise');
        $labels['country_id'] = \Yii::t('user', 'Country');
        return $labels;
    }




}
```

Comment: Hi @chapskev have you make it work? dont you get and error: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' because the profile table has user_id instead of id.  I cant make it work

Comment: @open-ecommerce.org yes it's working. In your table do you have id or use_id cause am sure that if in your table you have id instead of user_id you will run into an error. Best case scenario is that you use migrations

Comment: @chpskev thanks a lot for answering.  but if i change user_id to id I will get into problems because these come from the dektrium module

Comment: I am not understanding at what point your getting the exception and if you are using your own custom model. Have you ask a question on stack overflow ? Regarding this ? I need more details on this in order for to assist. You see table user and profile both have id and user_id respectively. So state at which point your getting the error. @open-ecommerce.org

Comment: I am doing exactly the same that you are doing adding new fields to the dektrium\user\models\Profile model.  First I created a migration to add the fields to the table profile that comes with the dektrium Yii2-user module.  I manage also to add the fields to the form but when I save the changes it dosent work because I think i need to create the rules. Thats why i am adding this class to extend the Profile class but dosn't work because yii expect an id instead of the original field id_user.  must be a way to say to the model that the primary key is id_user instead. in the

Comment: Create a question for this and share sample code. I Understand what your trying to do and as per your explanation I don't think you should run into problems. So we can assist you debug from your code. Also kindly mention the version of yii2-user that you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, remove this lines:

```
public $profile_pic;
public $expertise_id;
public $country_id;
```

If you already added those fields in the table, you dont need to declare them. As you can see, none of the others properties are being declared either. This is already being done by extending the model from `ActiveRecord` and declaring the `tableName`